# NumberFormatter string as minor currency unit not major with locale (e.g 99p not £0.99)

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

We use this function to convert an SKProduct into a localised price per item for our consumable bundles:

```
static func pricePerUnit(_ product: SKProduct, quantity: NSDecimalNumber) -> String? {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale

    let pricePerItem = product.price.dividing(by: quantity)

    guard let formattedPricePerItem = numberFormatter.string(from: pricePerItem) else {
        return nil
    }

    return "\(formattedPricePerItem) each"
}
```

For example, a bundle of 10 items for £9.99 becomes £0.99 for a UK user or $0.99 for a US user.

Ideally, if the amount is less than a single unit of the currency (aka one dollar), we'd like it to display with the minor currency unit (such as cents, pence, etc.).

I can't find a NumberFormatter style for this or any answer elsewhere. Can this be done using NumberFormatter?

Comment: This is out of scope for `NumberFormatter`. Actually, I believe the necessary data are not even present in the `Locale` data. You would need another currency symbol (or a text, e.g. `1 cent`, `5 cents`) and even the scaling factor to divide currency with (e.g. `100` for USD). If you need something like that, you will need to create your own localization data, at least for the major currencies.

Comment: Well, it appears that such formatting is not even standardized in Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done using `NumberFormatter`. `NumberFormatter` uses `Locale` to get currency format, including the number of decimal digits, positive patterns, negative patterns, currency symbols etc.

(see [Number Format Patterns in Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Number_Format_Patterns))

However, the format for minor currencies is not standardized in Unicode (although some necessary data are, e.g. multiplicators) and it's not present in iOS `Locale` data.

Comment: Ergh was hoping not to hear this! Great digging though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting as cent and pence may not be directly supported by `NumberFormatter` but `NumberFormatter` is flexible enough so that you can configure it to your wishes. For example, one can create a helper struct that holds 2 `NumberFormatter`: one to format it in dollars and pounds, and one to format it in cent and pence.

```
struct CurrencyFormatter {
    private static let defaultFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()

    private static let alternativeFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.multiplier = 100
        return formatter
    }()

    static var alternativeCurrencySymbols = [
        "USD": "c",
        "GBP": "p"
    ]

    static func string(from number: NSNumber, locale: Locale) -> String? {
        var formatter = defaultFormatter

        if number.isLessThan(1),
            let currencyCode = locale.currencyCode,
            let alternativeCurrencySymbol = alternativeCurrencySymbols[currencyCode]
        {
            formatter = alternativeFormatter
            formatter.positiveSuffix = alternativeCurrencySymbol
            formatter.negativeSuffix = alternativeCurrencySymbol
        }

        formatter.locale = locale
        return formatter.string(from: number)
    }
}

let number = NSNumber(value: 0.7)
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
if let str = CurrencyFormatter.string(from: number, locale: locale) {
    print(str) // result: 70p
}
```

The solution has a built-in fail safe mechanism. If you haven't defined the alternative symbol for a currency, it will fall back to the default currency format. You can test it by changing the locale to `fr_FR` and the result becomes `0,70 €`.